# Central limit theorem slightly modified

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, central-limit-theorem

Assume that we have independently and identically distributed random variables  $\left(X_n\right)_{n \in N}$ with finite and non-zero variance.
Consider the sequence
$$ Z_n :=\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i- E(X_i))}{\sqrt {\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)+5}}.$$

It seems kind of obvious to me that this series also converges towards a N(0,1) distributed random variable in distribution but how do I prove this?

Comment: Consider writing it as (something) times what you'd like the ratio to look like. Can you say what happens to the "something" in the limit?  Can you apply a handy theorem to the product of the two terms?

Comment: haha no real world problem. im preparing for an exam and I am looking for exercises and i stumbled upon it and I thought it was interesting. 
I guess I multiply with  $\frac{\sqrt{(var(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i)))+5}}{\sqrt{(var(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i)))}}$ so one term of the product converges against 1 and I can apply the CLT to the other one. but what to do from there?

Comment: As I said, you need to think about what theorems there are for this situation. You want something that talks about convergence when there's a product or ratio of two random variables, one of which converges in probability to a constant. (assuming you can show that "something" term converges in probability to a constant). Have you studied any theorems at all that relate to convergence of random variables (besides the CLT)?

Comment: I have an idea: I can interprete the two components of the product as a 2d vector and then apply the continuous function that multiplies the components with each other. I know that $g(X_n)$ converges towards $g(X)$  in distribution if $X_n$ converges towards $X$ in distribution and g is continuous.

Comment: I was thinking to just apply Slutsky's theorem myself, but if you can make that work, sure.